# Observable.CombineLatest bind and subscribe RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I am working on an app that uses an API that have some inconsistencies, I have achieved a result with these 2 observables that perform some shared actions but the first one '**servers**' is an array that binds to the UITableView.

```
    serversViewModel.servers
        .asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .bind(to: serversTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ServersTableViewCell.identifier, cellType: ServersTableViewCell.self)) { [weak self] (row, element, cell) in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            cell.serverProxy.accept(element)
            if let currentServer = strongSelf.serversViewModel.currentServer.value,
                element == currentServer,
                let index = strongSelf.serversViewModel.servers.value.firstIndex(where: { $0 == currentServer }){

                strongSelf.serversTableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)

            }

        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    serversViewModel.currentServer
        .asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (server) in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            if let server = server, let index = strongSelf.serversViewModel.servers.value.firstIndex(where: { $0 == server }){
                strongSelf.serversTableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
            }
            else{
                strongSelf.serversTableView.deselectAllItems(animated: false)
            }

        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Is it possible to create a combined observable for both and use it for binding the UITableView?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `combineLatest`. Note that most of this should actually be in your view model...

In the below code, the `servers` constant is a tuple of both the array of Server objects that should be displayed and the index path of the current server. Whenever either emits a new value, `servers` will emit a value.

You might find the following article helpful in the future: [Recipes for Combining Observables in RxSwift](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f)

```
let servers = Observable.combineLatest(serversViewModel.servers, serversViewModel.currentServer) { (servers, server) -> ([Server], IndexPath?) in
    let indexPath = server.flatMap { servers.firstIndex(of: $0) }
        .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
    return (servers, indexPath)
}

servers
    .map { $0.0 }
    .bind(to: serversTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ServersTableViewCell.identifier, cellType: ServersTableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
        cell.serverProxy.accept(element)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

servers
    .map { $0.1 }
    .bind(onNext: { [serversTableView] indexPath in
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            serversTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
        }
        else {
            serversTableView.deselectAllItems(animated: false)
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach from a slightly different way.  First I would consider pulling the combine observable back into the ViewModel you have already structured.  No need for this composition to be in your ViewController.

Then output *that* composed signal to bind into your rx.items.
You can wrap your objects will a table cell view model to control whether to show them in a 'selected state'

Then also output the currentServer from your viewModel to simply scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to combine observables in RxSwift. For your specific case, you will have to choose one that suits your needs best. Some of the operators are:

`combineLatest`
`zip`
`merge`
etc.

Read this [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) to get more idea about what each one it does.

Comment: which one would you suggest in my case?

Comment: What does each of your observable do? What do you want to be your final result?

Comment: when 'currentServer' is changed, it needs to select the UITableViewCell but because 'servers' is bind to the UITableView, the selection will go away. I need to bind the UITableView and select the UITableViewCell accordingly to the selected server.

Comment: So here, the selection as you said will go away, is because the 'servers' does not change when 'currentServer' changes. Ideally, you should have one instance of data source that defines your entire table view logic. What you can do here is when you get the currentServer change, make the same change in servers also so that `bind` gets called too and your view is in sync with servers